# oracle sql developer not showing a table's foreign keys in the constraints tab

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Where can I find the foreign key fields for a table in Oracle SQL Developer?

Oracle SQL Developer 4.0.2.15
Version 4.0.2.15
Build 15.21

IDE Version: 12.1.3.2.41.140418.1111
Product ID: oracle.sqldeveloper
Product Version: 12.2.0.15.21

### Version

Component   Version
=========   =======
Oracle IDE  4.0.2.15.21
Java(TM) Platform   1.7.0_55
Versioning Support  4.0.2.15.21

I do not see foreign keys displayed when a table is double clicked and then selecting the "Constraints" tab. (I only see Primary_Key and Check constraint types.) I also right click the table and hit "Edit", then constraints but only see primary keys. I have created a new tab that displays "FK References" by importing an XML file into SQL Developer but that new tab is never populated with foreign keys.

This is the contents of the fk_ref.xml file that I got from an answer on foreign keys in stackoverflow but it does not display foreign keys:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<items>


-<item vertical="true" node="TableNode" type="editor">


-<title>

-<![CDATA[FK References]]>
</title>


-<query>


-<sql>

-<![CDATA[select a.owner,
                            a.table_name,
                            a.constraint_name,
                            a.status
                     from   all_constraints a
                     where  a.constraint_type = 'R'
                            and exists(
                               select 1
                               from   all_constraints
                               where  constraint_name=a.r_constraint_name
                                      and constraint_type in ('P', 'U')
                                      and table_name = :OBJECT_NAME
                                      and owner = :OBJECT_OWNER)
                               order by table_name, constraint_name]]>
</sql>

</query>

</item>

</items>
```

Comment: Are you sure your table has a foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

Version 4.2 is rather old, maybe it just works like that. How about upgrading to a more recent version? It is free, after all ...

Because, on my 18.3, I can normally see foreign key constraint on the "Constraints" tab.

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot! I will look into that.

Comment: Unfortunately installing version 19.2.1.247 did not bring the foreign keys in. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hm, why do I see them, then? Are my foreign keys different than yours? Strange ...

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem while looking at an application's db schema.
I found the reason listed here, https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2011/01/foreign-keys-a-foreign-concept could be one of the reasons.
Basically the foreign key constraints maybe outside the database.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)